# Signature is not visible until after resize on modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, signaturepad

At my appliction after user enter data he needs to sign,
I'm using signature-pad plugin: https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad
and put the signature in modal of bootstrap4.

The issue is that before I open the modal, the canvas inside it has size of 0x0 pixels, so I need to resizing the screen and initializing the library whene the modal is opened.

I tried send the modal-body when calculate the width.
I put width and heigth manual - dosnt work good.

```
<script>
      $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        console.log("modal open");
        resizeCanvas();
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: kindly share a minimal, verifiable, complete example code so that anyone from the community can easily help

Comment: What about initializing the signature pad when the modal opens? Something like `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {/*Your settings*/});});` You could also add an if statement to see if it's allready been initialized or not.

Answer (score 1):

tnx guys, I finally got it.
I gave the modal style="display:block;"
and then by jq I change it

```
$(document).ready(function (){
            $('#myModal').css('display','none');
      });
```

and diabled the screen resize at signature-pad.